# When creating a custom build for OpenLayers3 some methods are obfuscated

Tags: openlayers-3, google-closure-compiler

When creating an OL3 build based on https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/config/ol.json
I am able to access the `ol.Map#renderSync` prototype method. However, if I use the following custom `"exports": [...]` array (to trim library size), `#renderSync` is obfuscated (or perhaps removed):

```
[
    "ol.Map",
    "ol.View",
    "ol.control.*",
    "ol.interaction.*",
    "ol.style.*",
    "ol.layer.Tile",
    "ol.layer.Group",
    "ol.source.XYZ",
    "ol.layer.Layer",
    "ol.layer.Vector",
    "ol.format.GeoJSON",
    "ol.source.Vector",
    "ol.Overlay",
    "ol.has.*",
    "ol.events.condition.*",
    "ol.inherits"
]
```

How can I export a custom, trimmed down, build without losing access to `ol.Map#renderSync` while (ideally) retaining closure `ADVANCED` optimization?

Comment: hi there, you could give some feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any `ol.Map` method you want to use, add it to `exports` section:

```
"exports": [
  "ol.Map",
  "ol.Map#updateSize",
  "ol.Map#renderSync",
  "ol.View",
  "ol.View#*",
  ...
]
```

Or use an asterisk to export all methods:

```
"exports": [
  "ol.Map",
  "ol.Map#*",
  ...
]
```

Comment: Perfect - I wouldn't have thought that the methods would be included separately from the class constructor!